# Remove special characters from string using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, newform

How to remove special characters from string. If user provided any special character from the below set of characters that should be removed:

> | \ " ' / [ ] : < > + = , ; ? * @

I tried regex. But it is not replacing. Please find below code:

```
var subSiteTitleval=$("input[title='Subsite Title Required Field']").val();

subSiteTitleval= subSiteTitleval.replace(/[@><,:;][+=?"'*/|]/g, ' ');

$("input[title='Subsite Title Required Field']").val(subSiteTitleval);
});
```

Kindly respond.

Comment: please ask the question in correct forum : https://stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var subSiteTitleval=$("input[title='Subsite Title Required Field']").val();

subSiteTitleval= subSiteTitleval.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-. ]/g, ' ');

$("input[title='Subsite Title Required Field']").val(subSiteTitleval); });
```

If you don't want to remove some of the special characters, just add inside regex like this

> /[^a-zA-Z0-9-. &]/g

You can refer to [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/06dJ3A/preview)